# React Native (Expo) clear cache Implement button

Tags: android, ios, react-native, clear-cache

I know that you can clear the cache in the command line.

for npm
`npm start --reset-cache`

for expo
`expo start -c`

But I want the user to be able to clear the cache from the app with a button. Is there a clear cache command in the code?

Or do I have to install a package for this?

THX.

I want to write a simple code to be able to clear the cache from inside the app